# How to add Custom Css and Javascript to tinymce in wordpress.

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, tinymce

I'm looking for a way to enhance the functionality of the TinyMCE editor in WordPress by adding my own custom script (css & JS) to improve it.

Please, Is there a hook to call that can make this happen?

Thanks.

Comment: you can add a plugin in your wordpress website to enable custom CSS and JS. For example, https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-css-js/

Comment: I'm talking of tinymce.

Answer (score 0):

Old question but since it's on top of google search results without answer I'm gonna chip in here.

In modern versions of Wordpress TinyMCE's iframe is not loaded as an external resource (file) but is generated on the fly and its content is injected by JS.

As such you also have access to its context and content directly in JS from the top window of your admin page.

Say, you want to manipulate classic editor's TinyMCE in main content editor i.e. dynamically change its color. You could just write in any script enqueued in admin panel something like this:

```
document.getElementById('content_ifr').contentWindow.document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
```

assuming id of the iframe is `#content_ifr`.

Or in jQuery:

```
$($('#content_ifr').get(0).contentWindow.document.body).attr('style', 'background-color:red');
```

If for any reason you still need to add JS to iframe's head section you can do it like this in your main JS file enqueued in admin:

```
let $script = document.createElement('script');
$script.innerHTML = 'console.log("Hello from TinyMCE iframe")';
document.getElementById('content_ifr').contentWindow.document.head.appendChild($script);
```

or if you need enqueue external file:

```
let $script = document.createElement('script');
$script.src = 'path/to/your-tinymce-custom-script.js';
$script.type = "text/javascript";
document.getElementById('content_ifr').contentWindow.document.head.appendChild($script);
```

Note that scripts appended to iframe's document will get executed immediately. I.e. in example above the console.log will immediately print `"Hello from TinyMCE iframe"` to the web dev console.

To add your main script to admin section you do it the usual way with admin_enqueue_scripts action i.e.

```
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', function() {
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'my-custom-admin-script',
        'path/to/your-custom-admin-script.js',
        [],
        1,
        true
    );  
} );
```

Answer (score -1):

Detailed help on TinyMCE - https://codex.wordpress.org/TinyMCE
I think that you should use the codex.

Comment: I can't find how to add custom JS. Already figured out the CSS part.

Comment: Can somehow so:

Comment: function wp_simple_example() { ?>
    <script>
        {script_code}
    </script>
    OR
    wp_enqueue_scripts(parametrs) - https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_enqueue_scripts 
    <?php
}
add_action( 'after_wp_tiny_mce', 'wp_simple_example' );

Comment: Thank you, Nikolay.